# PHP: why is this null different from the other null

Tags: php, variables, null, session

hi i tried 2 things what should be the same however it my testing says different does anyone know why the only thing i do is put it in a variable...

```
    if ($_SESSION[$something] === null)
        echo("this is null");
```

$_SESSION[$something] does not exists so it indeed says: "this is null".
now look at this

```
$theSession = $_SESSION[$something];

if ($theSession === null)
    echo("this is null");
```

now it does not say "this is null" while it should be exactly the same right?

Comment: Did you forget the `$` in your second snippet, before `theSession`?

Comment: my bad left the $ its suposed to be with the $

Answer (score 3):

You need a $ in front of `theSession` in the second block of code.

You do may not need the $ in front of `something`. You only need it if $something is holding a string of the session variable name. Otherwise if something is the session variable name you dont need the $.

Comment: Most likely the $ in $something _is_ useful, like in `$something='xyz'; echo $_SESSION[$something]; `

Comment: also if you get rid of the $ you need to quote the string

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using [is_null](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) to check is a variable contains a null value.

Comment: Any particular reason? The comments on that documentation page say it's slower (by a completely unimportant margin, but still).

Comment: Readability primarily. if (is_null($$something)) { ... is as about as straightforward as it gets.